# Group by elements of a value

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 3 KeyValuePairs:

```html
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
    {
        ["a"] = new List<int>{1,2},
        ["b"] = new List<int>{2,3},
        ["c"] = new List<int>{4,5}
    };
```

I need to group it by the same elements, so as result I expect to have as follows:

```
var result = new Dictionary<List<string>, List<int>>
{
    [new List<string> { "a"}] = new List<int> { 1 },
    [new List<string> { "b"}] = new List<int> { 3 },
    [new List<string> { "a", "b"}] = new List<int> { 2 },
    [new List<string> { "c"}] = new List<int> { 4, 5 }
};
```

What would the best ways to get the result?

Comment: using `List<string>` as a key of dictionary is not a very good idea. At least unless you provide custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use `SelectMany` to flatten the data structure. This leads to the following structure:

```
a | 1
a | 2
b | 2
b | 3
c | 4
c | 5
```

You can then group these data by the integers, so that you receive the following groups:

```
1 | a
2 | a, b
3 | b
4 | c
5 | c
```

After that, you can again group by the character sets, so that you have the following result:

```
1    | a
2    | a, b
3    | b
4, 5 | c
```

You can convert this into a dictionary (but be careful with lists as dictionary keys - lists are mutable so that you might not be able to find the elements later on; also lists are compared by reference if there is no comparer specified).

The following code creates the groups:

```
var grouped =  dict
  .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { i = y, k = x.Key }))
  .GroupBy(x => x.i)
  .Select(x => new { Key = x.Select(y => y.k).ToList(), Value = x.Key })
  .GroupBy(x => string.Join("|", x.Key.OrderBy(x => x)))
  .Select(x => new { Key = x.First().Key, Value = x.Select(y => y.Value).ToList() });
var result = grouped.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2vykjw) to test.

Comment: The key "c" is duplicated.

Comment: @shingo thanks for pointing this out. I've taken this into account and extended the code.

Comment: before join'ing numbers, if they are not sorted you may end up two strings such as a 1|2 and 2|1

Comment: @NuriTasdemir great observation. I've added the `OrderBy`